Meta query multiply key value from ACF based on taxonomy
How can i multiply 'key' in meta query? It is number field and i need automatically multiply value by 25. Thi is my current code:

if (isset($_POST['price_max']) && !empty($_POST['price_max'])) {
    $price_max = sanitize_text_field($_POST['price_max']);
    
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        // Případ pro ČR (cena v CZK)
        array(
            'key' => 'cena_podniku',
            'value' => $price_max,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        // CZK TO EUR
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'cena_podniku',
                'value' => $price_max,
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '<=',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'zeme',
                'value' => array('ČR'),
                'compare' => 'NOT IN',
            )
        ),
    );
}

And what i need to do is change value of key 'key' => 'cena_podniku', somehow like this 'key' => 'cena_podniku' * 25.

Multiplying the key, can't see how that could make much sense? Do you maybe want to multiply the value it is getting compared to - 'value' => $price_max * 25,? If that's not it, then you really need to give a better explanation, of what you actually want to achieve here.
